# Immutable value never used in for in loop

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm learning Swift and have started a Playground in Xcode 9.2. I've got the following code and whilst it is running as expected, it's giving me an warning message. What does it mean? I tried searching elsewhere but I can't find out why it's returning a warning.

```
for myCounter in 1...3 {

    print("My counter")

}
```

The warning:

> Immutable value 'myCounter' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it

I tried doing what it said, and it seemed to work and not return any warnings, but why would that make a difference?

```
for _ in 1...3 {

    print("My counter")

}
```

What's the difference here and why does it cause this?

Comment: It basically says you don't use the `myCounter` value
You could write `print("my counter: \(myCounter)")` and you will print the text + the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is telling that you are not using `myCounter` for anything, when you don't care about something in Swift you use `_` to tell the compiler that your intention is to not use that value.

The warnings would also go away if you started using the value:

```
for myCounter in 1...3 {
    print("My counter: \(myCounter)")

}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. Handy about using the underscore instead, doesn't seem very obvious to newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Swift has a smart compiler which optimizes. You are assigning 1, 2, and 3 into variable storage, to no purpose; you never *use* that variable for anything. So that is a waste of time and storage space. Therefore the compiler *warns* you to try to get you to improve the program. You did. It stopped warning.

Comment: *"the compiler cannot optimize it away"* – I am not sure about that. The compiler  might store the loop variable in a register only, or completely unroll the loop.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I thought about that too; I'll take out that phrase.

Comment: Actually the generated assembly code for both versions is *identical.*